# Cannot figure out why I pass an array of JavaScript objects to controller method that the controller method isn't getting the object

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I been looking around for awhile now and have came across this question many times and I am doing the same thing that are in the solutions but baffled why its not working.
I'm sure this question will be marked as a duplicate, and it is, but I am missing something.

Here is the array of JavaScript objects

```
var gridData = {
    tempData: [
        { UserName: "Tom", LastName: "Solomon" },
        { UserName: "Harry", LastName: "Solomon" },
        { UserName: "Sally", LastName: "Solomon" },
        { UserName: "Dick", LastName: "Solomon" },
    ]
};
```

Here is my Ajax

```
function TossIt() {
    var sendThis = gridData.tempData;
    console.log(sendThis);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Junk/JAT?s=" + sendThis,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(sendThis),
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { },
        complete: function (e) {
        }
    })
}
```

Here is the method I am passing it to

```
[HttpPost]
public List<Stuff> JAT(Stuff s)
{
    List<Stuff> result = new List<Stuff>();


    return result;
}
```

and here is the class

```
public class Stuff
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
```

I have a break point on the JAT method and s is always null

**EDIT**
I need to manipulate some of the properties in objects then return the list

Comment: Your url needs to be just `url: "/Junk/JAT",` (you cannot send a javascript array of objects as a query string) and `data: JSON.stringify({ result: sendThis }),`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, you always seem to come to my rescue.. If you want to post that as your answer and possibly explain why it needs to be done the way you said then I would be more than happy to mark it as an answer

Comment: Its still a bit unclear what your wanting to post here - your ajax is sending a collection but the POST method parameter is a single `Stuff` (if you want to bind to all the values your sending, the method parameter should be `List<Stuff>`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I made that change in my code and made the parameter a List<Stuff>

Comment: And you also specifying `dataType: 'json',` but your method does not return json so your would be getting a `500 (internal Server Error)` What are you really wanting to return (you don't do anything in the success callback)? And why would you want to return an empty collection anyway?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I wasn't really wanting to return anything, not yet anyways, it was testing before I broaden it and put into production.. I'm going to be pushing objects into an array and need to pass the array of objects to a controller and do some work on the it and return the list. It'll be a bigger method than what was shown.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137805/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-chris).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code

1. You cannot send a javascript array of objects in a query string
   parameter and your url needs to be just `url: '/Junk/JAT',`, or
   preferably `url: @Url.Action("JAT", "Junk");` which will ensure the
   url is correctly generated (as a side note, to bind the model from a
   query string, it would need to be
   `/Junk/JAT?[0].UserName=Tom&[0].LastName=Solomon&[1].UserName=Harry&.....`)
2. Your sending an array of objects representing a `Stuff`, therefore
   the parameter in the POST method must also implement
   `IEnumerable<Stuff>` (not a single `Stuff`)
3. Your specifying that the method return json (your use of `dataType: "json",`) so therefore the method must return a `JsonResult`.

You code should be

Script

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("JAT", "Junk")',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({ s: sendThis }),
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        .... // do something with the data you return
    },
    complete: function (e) {
    }
})
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult JAT(List<Stuff> s) // or ActionResult
{
    .... // manipulate the collection as required
    return Json(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPost]
public List<Stuff> JAT([FromBody]List<Stuff> s)
{
    List<Stuff> result = new List<Stuff>();


    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer above using `POST` is the way to go. However, **if** you want to do `GET` and `queryStrings`, you can as well.

Trivial example:

- Client side (see [`$.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/))

  ```
  var gridData = {
      tempData: [
          { UserName: "Tom", LastName: "Solomon" },
          { UserName: "Harry", LastName: "Solomon" },
          { UserName: "Sally", LastName: "Solomon" },
          { UserName: "Dick", LastName: "Solomon" },
      ]
  };

  function TossIt() {
      var sendThis = gridData.tempData;
      console.log(sendThis);
      $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "/JAT?" + $.param(gridData), //using $.param() here for query string            
          success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {},
          complete: function(e) {
          }
      });
  }
  ```
- `Controller` side

  - follow the above comments/answer regarding  `List<Stuff>`
  - `HttpGet` Attribute
  - Adjust the parameter name to `tempData` (re: `$.param()`)

    ```
    [System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]
    public List<Stuff> JAT(List<Stuff> tempData)
    {
       ......
    }
    ```

Hth...

Comment: @StephenMuecke Not so: `http://foo.com/JAT?tempData%5B0%5D%5BUserName%5D=Tom&tempData%5B0%5D%5BLastName%5D=Solomon...`

Comment: Ahh, I take that back - I thought you were using it on `sendThis` :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke yep  t'was `gridData` :)

Comment: Just copied your code and `tempData` contains 4 objects but all properties of each `Stuff` are `null`

Comment: The only way the `DefaultModelBinder` will bind to a collection of complex objects is if the query string is in the format I noted in point 1 of my answer.

Comment: @StephenMuecke +1 Arg, you're right about that ~ kinda makes it pointless (and have to go old school - `Request.QueryString["foo"]`)....

Comment: `$.param()` is fine for collections of simple values - e.g `{ tempdata: [ "abc', 'def' ] }` and binding to `IEumerable<string> tempdata`, just not for complex objects (but you would probably not want to pass collections of complex objects in a query string anyway - it risks exceeding the query string limit and throwing an exception)